# Jersey stuck when number of async connections become more then 7

Tags: java, ajax, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I implementing longpoll in Jersey+Grizzly. For testing my problem now I have just resource with asyncResponce, that suspending request. Like this:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public void asyncGetWithTimeout(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse response) {
            response.resume(Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                    .entity("{\"response\":\"timeout\"}").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build());
        }
    });
    asyncResponse.setTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

All work fine, until number of suspended request become more than 7. Then entire web-application stuck, even regular sync requests. How is it possible, is there only 7 threads in Jersey? Sorry, I'am not very good in concurrency and web-applications, just did't expected this kind of problem.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that 7 is not a magic number that gets it stuck... but I guess you know that already. Is always the same behavior? Have you tried different combinations of calls? My guess is that you must be running out of some resource, you have found out what is it.

Comment: Turns out it is a magic number =) See my own answer. Thanx for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. Actually there a client-side problem, knowns as "maximum number of connections per hostname". This number is browser/application specific. So I test my web-application in Chrome and get 7. As you can see from table below I just miscalculate this by 1.

Max Number of default simultaneous persistent connections per server/proxy:

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```